# Is it possible to perform a zero inflated poisson regression model in R with more than 4 variables?

Tags: r, model, poisson

This is my first time posting on here, so I apologize if this isn't the correct format/info. But I'm attempting to run a model in R with the zeroinfl function (pscl package). My data consists of insect count data and 5 different variables, which are 5 different habitat types.

## Zero inflation poisson model

summary(m1 <- zeroinfl(count~Hab_1+Hab_2+Hab_3+Hab_4+Hab_5, data = insect_data))

I'm able to run the model when I only use 4 variables in the equation, but when I add the fifth variable it gives me this error code:
Error in optim(fn = loglikfun, gr = gradfun, par = c(start$count, start$zero,  :
non-finite value supplied by optim

Is there a way to run a zero inflated model using all 5 of these variables or am I missing something? Any input would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The specific number of variables in the model is not the issue. But is it possible that there are only zero or only non-zero counts for `Hab_5`? If you run a logistic regression model on the whether the outcome is zero or non-zero, do you get the same issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no, each habitat type has both zero and non-zero counts...thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: You could still have a complete separation problem when `Hab_5` is added if some combination of `Hab_5` and one or more other predictor variables results in complete separation of the zero and non-zero counts. In that case there isn't a unique set of parameters that maximizes the likelihood.